# Jitter Physics not working correctly. Going through objects and getting pushed back when touching walls

Tags: c#, xna, physics, monogame

I am trying to use the [Jitter physics engine](https://github.com/mattleibow/jitterphysics), however, I can't get it to work correctly. For example, when I touch the side of a cube, it pushes me far back in the opposite direction. While I am flying back, if I hold the opposite directional key, I keep getting slower until I come to full stop.

Other times, I go right through the floor. I followed this [tutorial](http://web.archive.org/web/20150627075053/http://jitter-physics.com/Tutorial.pdf).

I gave my floors `BoxShapes` and a `RigidBody`. I set them to `static` so the rigidbodies won't move. I did the same in my `Player` class but didn't set it to static.

How do I make it work correctly? If someone knows a better tutorial or physics engine I can use in C# with MonoGame/XNA, please let me know.

Comment: [Bennett Foddy gave a great GDC talk in 2015 about general troubleshooting methods to improve the stability of game physics](http://gdcvault.com/play/1021921/Designing-with-Physics-Bend-the). Users checking out this question might find some useful advice there.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I used Jitter, but here's my two cents:

- The push-back happens because a force is applied to your character in order to avoid penetration with the wall. Setting `World.ContactSettings.BiasFactor` to a lower value should reduce the force used, but may also cause slight penetration or other issues.
- I had a similar problem with errant collision, which was caused by a
  Jitter bug. If you are using the 0.1.7.0 version (the last download, from Oct 2011), you
  are affected by it. The first line in `JVector.TransposedTransform`
  should be

  `float num0 = ((position.X * matrix.M11) + (position.Y * matrix.M12)) + (position.Z * matrix.M13);`

  The incorrect version has `M31` instead of `M13`.
- I don't know about current .Net physics engines, but Jitter certainly seems long since abandoned and somewhat incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your faces are oriented the right way; use IDebugDrawer to verify this.

Comment: This answer would be better if it gave some more details about how to use IDebugDrawer to check this - eg. what methods should the user call, and how should they interpret the results they see? If the faces are oriented incorrectly, what should they do to fix it? This kind of detail will tend to attract more upvotes. ;)